# Chrome crashes in Android Studio Emulator when using API 24 Nougat

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-7.0-nougat

When using Android Studio, a virtual device that is to API 24 (Nougat) seems to have a problem connecting to the Internet.  Chrome crashes and is unable to load any pages.  API 23 devices seem to connect normally with no issues so this seems to be a problem only with API 24.

Does anyone know how to resolve this connectivity issue when launching an API24 virtual device in Android Studio?

Comment: I'm with the same issue here. Did you solved it?